# jQuery button to switch Tablesorter column's filter from select to input and viceversa

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I've been trying to make a text switchable jQuery button to replace a specific column's HTML dropdown select to input and vice versa.

[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3lh6.png)-->[insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9ViN.png)-->[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3lh6.png) ...

But it seems like the search calls stop working, I guess there's a proper workable way to do this which does not simply involve replacing HTML.

Comment: Could you not have 2 hidden fields, then just hide one and show the other, then reverse when clucked again

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using css. Here's an example using the css display property.

```js
function toggleInput() {
  if ($("#inputBox").hasClass("hide")) {
      $("#selectBox").addClass("hide");
      $("#inputBox").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  } else {
    $("#inputBox").addClass("hide");
    $("#selectBox").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleInput()">Toggle input type</button>
<select id="selectBox">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
<input class="hide" id="inputBox" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery Tablesorter by Mottie? The question would become how would I actually evoke both elements in the 1st place for the same column,

Comment: Is there a way to get a minimal working sample? Not really sure what you mean by "evoke both elements"